# How do I model similar types that have different data?

Tags: design

We're working on a bugtracking system.

Our design has a BugReport class that represents the filing of a bug of some Project in the system. BugReports have tags, representing the state/progress of the BugReport. Possible tags are e.g. New, Closed, Duplicate, Under Review, ...

Tags have no responsibility other than representing the progress of the BugReport. Except for one special type of tag, Duplicate. Duplicate means that the BugReport is actually a duplicate of another BugReport in the system. When a user tags a BugReport as Duplicate, he should indicate of which BugReport the BugReport is a Duplicate of.

I'm having trouble to design this part. As said before, most tags only have the functionality of representing the progress of the BugReport. Except for one (maybe more in the future) which also has the functionality to point to another BugReport.

A simple enum would've sufficed if not for the Duplicate part, but I have no idea how to provide the extra functionality of Duplicate?

Comment: Represent "Duplicate" separately from other tags. Its nature is entirely different. The actual tag that goes with is "Closed". Separately from tracking the progress, you want something to track why a ticket was closed: fixed, not a bug, could not duplicate, duplicate, new feature, will not fix, etc.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That shifts the problem from the status to the disposition field, but I don't see how it solves the underlying problem.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: A fair number of "closed" reasons are going to have references to "other stuff"--another ticket in the case of a duplicate, a hash in the case of fixed, a design document in the case of not a bug, etc. So basically, for any disposition you have a Boolean to say whether a reference is needed, and possibly some way of specifying the type of the reference (but possibly not--you might just use a URI for all of them). Bottom line: you're going to have to solve the general problem for disposition anyway.

Comment: That still leaves you with a design that breaks when the users decide they want "under review" to reference a reviewer.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the status field needs to be able to handle additional data, because even if you turn "Duplicate" into something other than a state, some other state will inevitably have the need for additional data as the program evolves. I'm basically saying that the OP's statement "a simple enum would've sufficed" is wrong.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: It's certainly true that I haven't attempted to design an entire bug tracking system in one comment thread. That does't mean the design is broken. It just means I haven't solved *every* possible problem here. But I agree that there are probably references needed for states other than "Closed" (e.g., when confirming a bug, a reference to a test that shows it).

Comment: Interesting discussion. It certainly gave me more insight. It is likely that extensions such as the ones you mentioned are going to be needed in the system in the future. I'm not an advanced software designer at all. What is "specifying the type of the reference" (@Jerry Coffin)? How?

Comment: @Auberon: Specifying the type of reference would mean that you have (for example) a text field to specify the reference itself, and some associated field (possibly an enumeration) to tell how that would be interpreted (plain text, URI/URL, etc.)

Comment: This question has a follow up question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/313301/design-decision-exposing-information#313301

Answer (score 2):

The information *New, Closed, Duplicate, Under Review,* and similar correspond to states of a BugReport.

Simple states are usually represented with an indicator or an enum.  If you have only one exception, you could just use an optional association to another BugReport, with the remark that it shall be used only in the case of duplicates.

However another cleaner alternative would be to use the [State design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).  This is very powerful:  the states are modeled as class, each state inheriting from a basic state, and encapsulating if necessary state-dependent data and behaviors.  It is very powerful and maintenable.

[image]

Comment: Your first suggestion was our first implementation but we're reviewing that to protect the design from future extensions. The State pattern is something we've considered. You claim State is "encapsulating (...) state-dependent data and behaviours". While I agree with the behaviour part, I'm not so sure for the data part. How would Duplicate State keep a reference to another BugReport while the others do not keep any reference and still be accessible from the State interface?

Comment: I've considered Decorator as well. Since Duplicate adds extra functionality to a Tag. As far as I know, it isn't possible to extend Tag's functionality (which is an extra reference) using the pattern. Even if we could, how would one access the reference from the interface?

Comment: I've updated with a quick picture of a possible model, showing how state could take care of state specific data.  Note also that it would be very easy to keep an history of the sates (either with active state + container of past states, or a stack of states, the top being the active one)

Comment: Decorator could be an option as well.  However, all the other objects referencing the bug shall then reference the decorator instead, because the decorator has to be up-front the decorated object (i.e. you have to refer to the decorated object and not to the object with a decoration).  I think this makes it a little bit impractical.

Comment: Yes. This kind of design was exactly what I was thinking. However, if the user gets the BugState from a BugReport (which is of type BugState), how can he access the fields from the implementing classes (e.g. The BugReport reference in Duplicate)? That's the main question here. Either that wasn't clear or I'm missing something simple.

Comment: @Auberon In answer to your question. Stop asking "how do I access state?", the general rule is that you don't access state. The state is encapsulated. A BugReport would know how to display itself (possibly through another Strategy object) in a particular medium. Part of its displaying itself would be to pass the medium to the BugState object so it can display *itself* (hence the `showState()` method in the interface. In short, whatever code thinks it needs the `duplicate` should be passed to the BugState to use.

Comment: The best way would probably to encapsulate this functionality into a polymorphic method of the BugState class. For example, here, showState() could be implemented to display the name corresponding to the state, and  "Duplicate of <ID of the ticker>" for this state. Another way could be to add an isDuplicate() member to the BugState.  Finally, you could add some  conditional code in BugReport to test the type of the State and perform state dependent actions, but this would create a strong dependency of BugReport to specific classes and would be  against the principle of separation of concerns.

Comment: I'm currently having a discussion with my peers about this. I would want to have `showState()` return a String representing the State. e.g. Under Review would return "The BugReport is under review." and Duplicate would return "The BugReport is a duplicate of duplicate.getTitle()" or something similar. My peers would want it to return the duplicate object instead, returning `null` when the tag isn't a duplicate. I think the latter isn't a good idea.

Comment: They also want to create an interface for every relevant object (i.e. IBugReport for BugReport) that defines methods that can be used by the user (such as the getters). The user would then be responsible to printing the representation of the object by using the getters as defined by the interface. I would have the system know how to represent an object. (e.g. a PrettyPrint class that visits [Visitor Pattern] e.g. BugReports and builds a String which can be given to the user). I'd give a penny for your thoughts. Is any of the previous bad design? Or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: I think the return value is a pragmatic approach. Not perfect but acceptable.  But I'd really prefer classes taking care of themselves via polymorphic behaviour, in methods defined at parent state level. This is simple, efficient and easy to maintain. If the handling needs however more complexity (e.g. Build dynamically the layout of a Ui dialog) i would opt for the visitor, in order to isolate dependencies and keep internals hidden for those objects that  don't need to know.

Comment: "taking care of themselves". Do you mean that the String representation of e.g. a BugReport should be created and printed to screen in the BugReport class? (e.g. in the BugReport class `public void printToScreen() { System.out.println(title + "\n" +  description); tag.printToScreen(); }` ) I realize these may be very nubile questions. Is there therefore any reference you recommend on the high level design (e.g. how to present the system to the user)? I have the GoF book but it doesn't cover that, I think. I think I'm missing some very obvious, basic principle.

Comment: With "taking care of themselves", I mean calling general state methods (that could be called from the BugReport) with a unique signature/interface, and let each state contribute with its specifics.  You should however avoid giving states responsibilities that it doesn't have (separation of concerns). For instance, if your BugRepport is a business logic object, it should remain independent of the GUI, so that you can use it in Windows, Gnome, OS/X or console applications.  Therefore it may be safer to foresee a string conversion, and leave the printing for the UI subsystem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37187/discussion-between-christophe-and-auberon).